# Why do these two GREP commands give different results?

Tags: sorting, grep, uniq, wc

I have a large log file containing lines for a particular task as follows:

```
[info] My task : 123
[info] Other task : 111
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 789
```

I want to count the number of unique `"My task"`s logged. Which in this case should be 3.

I have used these two commands which, in my opinion, should give the same and correct results:

```
grep 'My Task :' | uniq | wc -l
grep -E 'My Task :' | sort --unique | grep -cE 'My Task :'
```

The two commands give the same results on the small test files I create but different results on the large log file on the server. I cannot understand why. To be exact, the first command gives a count of ~33k while the second one gives ~15k. Which command of the two, if any is correct? And what should I ideally be doing?

Comment: There will 0 matches if you use `My Task` as `grep` is case-sensitive by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible it happens because `uniq` can only find *consecutive*
identical lines.  Say, if your file looks like this:

```
[info] My task : 123
[info] Other task : 111
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 789

[info] My task : 123
[info] Other task : 111
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 789

[info] My task : 123
[info] Other task : 111
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 789

[info] My task : 123
[info] Other task : 111
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 789

[info] My task : 123
[info] Other task : 111
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 456
[info] My task : 789
```

results will be different:

```
$ grep 'My task :' FILE | uniq | wc -l
15
$ grep -E 'My task :' FILE | sort --unique  | wc -l
3
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem:** `uniq` and `sort -u`
>
> They should be equivalent in the simple case, but will behave
>   differently if you're using the -k option to define only certain
>   fields of the input line to use as sort keys. In that case, **sort -u
>   will suppress lines which have the same key** even if other parts of the
>   line differ, whereas **uniq will only suppress lines that are exactly
>   identical**.

**Difference Between the Two Commands **

> 1st Command `grep 'My Task :' | uniq | wc -l`:     It prints the count
>   of lines which are unique for 'My Task'
>
> 2nd Command `grep -E 'My Task :' | sort --unique | grep -cE 'My Task'` :     It prints the count of matching pattern 'My Task'

**Discrepancy b/w the two depends on the contents of your log file.**

To answer your question which one to use:
When using `grep with -E` like you did try to make an apt pattern and then count the lines.

Answer (score 0):

No need multiple commands to count unique number.

```
awk '/My task/ {a[$NF]++;c+=a[$NF]==1?1:0} END {print c}' file
3
```

- `/My task/` do line contain `My task`, if yes:
- - `a[$NF]++` create an array with number as a key. First time a value is found it will be `1`, second time `2`, third time same value found it will be `3` etc
- - `c+=a[$NF]==1?1:0` if array a[number] is `1` (first time found), increment `c` with `1`, else add `0`
- `{print c}` print number of unique number from variable  `c`